# Python search webpage for element and print it to discord

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord, discord.py

Okay, i want to search a webpage for the first link in a h5 header like
`<h5><a href="http://example.org/anything/">anything</a></h5>`
1. How would i tell Python that 'anything' can be anything?
2. And how would i then print the hyperlink(or title) to Discord?

So far i've managed to get the source of a website using:

```
import requests

link = "http://www.example.com" f = requests.get(link)

print(f.text)
```

And i know i can print text to discord using:

```
@bot.command(pass_context=True)
async def latest-release(ctx):
    await bot.say("This should be the mentioned Link")
```

I did already follow this tutorial, but i cnat seem to import BeutifulSoup nor BeautifulSoup... https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/beautifulsoup/scraping-websites-with-beautifulsoup

Answer (score 0):

If you have installed bs4 through pip already, then you should be able to import it in Python 3 using

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
```

and from there, you turn your webpage into a soup and navigate towards your hyperlink

```
header = soup.find("h5")
# or:
# header = soup.h5
# header = soup.find_all("h5")[0]
# Returns None if "h5" can't be found
link = header.a
url = link["href"]
text = link.text
```

Here are the docs for [BeautifulSoup4](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#quick-start)

Comment: I get the following error:
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\Desktop\test.py", line 3, in <module>
    header = soup.find("h5")
NameError: name 'soup' is not defined`

Comment: Read the error. You need to turn the webpage into a soup object first.